# Swift switch case to use contents of array, syntax?

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax, switch-statement

The Swift Book from Apple has a switch example that uses vowels as a case.

**Question.**
Instead of having this list of vowels, is it possible to use an array that contained this contents? if so, what's the syntax for doing this?

---

~ from Apple Swift Book ~

> The following example removes all vowels and spaces from a lowercase
>   string to create a cryptic puzzle phrase:

```
let puzzleInput = "great minds think alike"
var puzzleOutput = ""
for character in puzzleInput.characters {
    switch character {
    case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", " ":
        continue
    default:
        puzzleOutput.append(character)
    }
}
print(puzzleOutput)
// Prints "grtmndsthnklk"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes:

```
let puzzleInput = "great minds think alike"
var puzzleOutput = ""
let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", " "]

for character in puzzleInput.characters {
    switch character {
    case _ where vowels.contains(character):
        continue
    default:
        puzzleOutput.append(character)
    }
}
```

`case` matching in Swift relies on the pattern matching operator (`~=`). If you define a new overload for it, you can shorten the code even more:

```
func ~=<T: Equatable>(pattern: [T], value: T) -> Bool {
    return pattern.contains(value)
}

for character in puzzleInput.characters {
    switch character {
    case vowels:
        continue
    default:
        puzzleOutput.append(character)
    }
}
```

Comment: Above and Beyond! THANK YOU! This is very elegant and powerful. Please excuse my ignorance, what does the pattern matching operator (` ~= `) mean/do?

Comment: @Confused It takes a pattern (in this case, an array of some type `T`, `[T]`), and a value (in this case, of some type `T`), and returns true if the pattern matches that value. What "matches" means is up to you, and is what the function body determines

Comment: Another common example you'll see is `~=` being used to check for ranges. For example, `0...10 ~= 5` returns true because the pattern `0...10` matches the value `5`, according to the definition of "matches" as defined by the operator's implementation. Because this operator exists, you can say `case 0...5` directly in a switch statement.

Comment: So it's sort of like a "has a" and "is a" combined? @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: @Confused Its exact meaning can be whatever define it to be. Here's an interesting example I just conjured up: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58008106db09af01efbe6699

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that logical AND and OR have completely rattled my mind when I was trying to figure out how bitmasks work in SKPhysics. And I'm still recovering. And today I'm struggling with && inside if conditions I'm trying to make work.

Comment: So the presence of another type of matching thing (~=) is doing my head in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125738/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-confused).